# Triangular transofrmation in numpy/python that is fast and doesn't eat up all memory

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have data as follows

```
[[1,2,3],
 [4,5,6],
 [7,8,9]]
```

I would like to triangularize it with a max row length.
so for an infinite max row length it would be

```
[[1],
 [1,2],
 [1,2,3],
 [1,2,3,4],
 [1,2,3,4,5],
 [1,2,3,4,5,6],
 ...
 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]]
```

if the max row length was 4

```
[[1],
 [1,2],
 [1,2,3],
 [1,2,3,4],
 [2,3,4,5],
 [3,4,5,6],
 ...
 [6,7,8,9]]
```

I am fine with zero padding as well so the above could be

```
[[1,0,0,0],
 [1,2,0,0],
 [1,2,3,0],
 [1,2,3,4],
 [2,3,4,5],
 [3,4,5,6],
 ...
 [6,7,8,9]]
```

I thought about making the entire last row concatenation, repeating the row, and then applying a triangular mask. However, with my dataset, I may run out of memory, so I incorporated the max row length.

Is there an efficient numpy way of computing this transformation that won't eat my memory? I'm open to using other libraries as well. Perhaps using a database or file storage in which I can partially load data might help as well. For context, this data will be going into a linear layer (for projection) then a transformer, so perhaps there are already ways of dealing with this, however, my google foo was not strong enough.

thanks, all!

Answer (score 1):

If you're fine with left padding this is exactly what [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html) is doing:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

a = np.array([[1,2,3],
              [4,5,6],
              [7,8,9]])

n = 4

swv(np.pad(a.ravel(), (n-1, 0), constant_values=0), 4)
```

As a **view** of the array is returned, this should be memory efficient.

Output:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4, 5],
       [3, 4, 5, 6],
       [4, 5, 6, 7],
       [5, 6, 7, 8],
       [6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

Comment: This works well for the scale I have now. Just got a computer with 1TB RAM so it should be fine. Let's say I didn't want the sliding window but to have no max row length. Do you know of any linear algebra library that can split tasking over computer with MPI or something? I'd rather not self roll my own stuff here, although this problem is fairly trivial for that.

Comment: @M46f988b814 no sorry, I'm not aware of such library. You could use a loop and slicing though.